# Breakdown form submitting blank data to database

Tags: php, sql, database

The issue has been briefly resolved and now the database add's a new line for the information, my only issue is that the database isn't getting any information from the form.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }



mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);



$sql="INSERT INTO breakdowns (username, breakdowndate, policyinception, customername, customersurname, covertype, vehiclemake, vehiclemodel, vehiclereg, vehicleage, excess, mileage, paid, HSRS, fault, garage, telephone)

VALUES

('$_POST[username]','$_POST[breakdowndate]','$_POST[policyinception]','$_POST[customername]','$_POST[customersurname]','$_POST[covertype]','$_POST[vehiclemake]','$_POST[vehiclemodel]','$_POST[vehiclereg]','$_POST[vehicleage]','$_POST[excess]','$_POST[mileage]','$_POST[paid]','$_POST[HSRS]','$_POST[fault]','$_POST[garage]','$_POST[telephone]')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo "1 breakdown added";



mysql_close($con)

?>
```

When the script is executed on the server I get the echo message and a blank lines appears in the database but no information from the form is present.

This is now working:

```
<?php
// This sends the breakdown form to the database //

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","dgtlss20_orca1","qG!P}ubT.tuw");

        if (!$con)

    {

        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    } 

    mysql_select_db("dgtlss20_orca", $con); 

        $sql="INSERT INTO breakdowns (username, breakdowndate, policyinception, customername, customersurname, covertype, vehiclemake, vehiclemodel, vehiclereg, vehicleage, excess, mileage, paid, HSRS, fault, garage, telephone)
        VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[breakdowndate]','$_POST[policyinception]','$_POST[customername]','$_POST[customersurname]','$_POST[covertype]','$_POST[vehiclemake]','$_POST[vehiclemodel]','$_POST[vehiclereg]','$_POST[vehicleage]','$_POST[excess]','$_POST[mileage]','$_POST[paid]','$_POST[HSRS]','$_POST[fault]','$_POST[garage]','$_POST[telephone]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

    {

    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    header('Location: ../breakdown-added.php');



        mysql_close($con)

?>
```

Comment: I removed the ; that was mentioned in this issue and now I have the following error


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VALUES' (T_STRING) in breakdown_handler.php on line 7

Comment: I have tried all of these with no luck, however the error code has gone from when the file is executed! so at least some progress is being made. Is there a way I could try this not using mysqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection

You need to pass parameters as `$_POST['post_breakdowndate']` instead of `$_POST[post_breakdowndate]`

You need to update your query into as

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (user, breakdowndate, policyinception, customername, customersurname, covertype, vehiclemake, vehiclemodel, vehiclereg, vehicleage, excess, mileage, paid, HSRS, fault, garage, telephone) VALUES ('".$_POST['post_user']."', '".$_POST['post_breakdowndate']."', '".$_POST['post_policyinception']."', '".$_POST['post_customername']."', '".$_POST['post_customersurname']."', '".$_POST['post_covertype']."', '".$_POST['post_vehiclemake']."', '".$_POST['post_vehiclemodel']."', '".$_POST['post_vehiclereg']."', '".$_POST['post_vehicleage']."', '".$_POST['post_excess']."', '".$_POST['post_mileage']."', '".$_POST['post_paid']."', '".$_POST['post_HSRS']."', '".$_POST['post_fault']."', '".$_POST['post_garage']."', '".$_POST['post_telephone']."')");
```

You are terminating that values part outside the function

Comment: I have updated code this will remove all those errors and work as charm

Comment: Sorry my bad I have updated my code @NathanLanger and I have updated the reason why its not working too. Revert me if an error occurs

Comment: Yes you can use `PDO`  prepare statement but it might be because you might be not getting values within `$_POST` try to echo query and place that query within sql

Comment: I have updated the code in the example at the top of the page, please can you take a look and see if there are any issues left in the code?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't recognize where. @NathanLanger

Comment: @NathanLanger you were doing the same mistake over here `$_POST['post_breakdowndate']` instead of `$_POST[post_breakdowndate]` and so on......

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqli_query function is not correctly written :

You have `mysqli_query(connection, "query"` followed by some code that should be inside the query and is not recognized as it should be, 
instead of `mysqli_query(connection, "query");`

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (user, breakdowndate, policyinception, customername, customersurname, covertype, vehiclemake, vehiclemodel, vehiclereg, vehicleage, excess, mileage, paid, HSRS, fault, garage, telephone) VALUES ('".$_POST[post_user]."', '".$_POST[post_breakdowndate]."', '".$_POST[post_policyinception]."', '".$_POST[post_customername]."', '".$_POST[post_customersurname]."', '".$_POST[post_covertype]."', '".$_POST[post_vehiclemake]."', '".$_POST[post_vehiclemodel]."', '".$_POST[post_vehiclereg]."', '".$_POST[post_vehicleage]."', '".$_POST[post_excess]."', '".$_POST[post_mileage]."', '".$_POST[post_paid]."', '".$_POST[post_HSRS]."', '".$_POST[post_fault]."', '".$_POST[post_garage]."', '".$_POST[post_telephone]."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You were terminating the query before it was ending with values. Try with -

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (user, breakdowndate, policyinception, customername, customersurname, covertype, vehiclemake, vehiclemodel, vehiclereg, vehicleage, excess, mileage, paid, HSRS, fault, garage, telephone) VALUES ('$_POST[post_user]', '$_POST[post_breakdowndate]', '$_POST[post_policyinception]', '$_POST[post_customername]', '$_POST[post_customersurname]', '$_POST[post_covertype]', '$_POST[post_vehiclemake]', '$_POST[post_vehiclemodel]', '$_POST[post_vehiclereg]', '$_POST[post_vehicleage]', '$_POST[post_excess]', '$_POST[post_mileage]', '$_POST[post_paid]', '$_POST[post_HSRS]', '$_POST[post_fault]', '$_POST[post_garage]', '$_POST[post_telephone]')");
```

Comment: This removed the error however it still isn't storing information to the database...

Comment: check the fields & variables & the credentials you are passing if they are correct or not.

Comment: been through and checked that all of my id and name tags are applicable to that of the file and still no luck. All names for the table and id's etc are the same throughout.

Answer (score 0):

If your column count and values count is same in the query, the below code will work:

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO posts (user, breakdowndate, policyinception, customername, customersurname, covertype, vehiclemake, vehiclemodel, vehiclereg, vehicleage, excess, mileage, paid, HSRS, fault, garage, telephone)".
"VALUES ('$_POST[post_user]', '$_POST[post_breakdowndate]', '$_POST[post_policyinception]', '$_POST[post_customername]', '$_POST[post_customersurname]', '$_POST[post_covertype]', '$_POST[post_vehiclemake]', '$_POST[post_vehiclemodel]', '$_POST[post_vehiclereg]', '$_POST[post_vehicleage]', '$_POST[post_excess]', '$_POST[post_mileage]', '$_POST[post_paid]', '$_POST[post_HSRS]', '$_POST[post_fault]', '$_POST[post_garage]', '$_POST[post_telephone]')");

?>
```